# How do I add a legend to the appropriate line in PGFPlots?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I've added a linear regression to my plot and I'd like to call out the linear regression as well as the formula for the line in my plot. How do I do that? I know it's super close to the actual data but what can I do to make this appear better?

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=6.25in,paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\today}
\lhead{xxx}


\pagenumbering{gobble}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{0pt}
%\addtolength{\paperheight}{-92pt}
%\addtolength{\paperwidth}{-92pt}
\usepackage{circuitikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(0,1)},anchor=north west},
ymin = 0.00071, 
ymax = 0.00214, 
clip = true,
clip mode=individual,
grid = major,
title=Voltage \& Current,
ylabel=Current,
xlabel=Voltage,
scaled ticks=false,
enlargelimits=0.2,
]
\addplot[opacity=.7,
scatter,
only marks,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
scatter/classes={
a={mark=square*,blue},%
b={mark=triangle*,red},%
c={mark=o,draw=black}},
]
table[meta=label] {
x y label
4.025 0.00071 b
6.042 0.00107 b
7.94 0.00140 b
9.98 0.00177 b
12 0.00214 b

 
};
\addplot [opacity=.5] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{
X Y
4.025 0.000706862
6.042 0.001067945
7.94 0.001407724
9.98 0.001772924
12 0.002134544
};

\legend{Voltage,Current}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Normally you add `\addlegendentry` after each `\addplot`.  See page 256 of pgfplots manual.

Comment: Yes, but the legend is not corresponding correctly with the right markers and colors.

Comment: Why are you using three scatter classes when there is just one set of points? The legend  corresponds to the first two scatter classes.

Comment: Ah, Okay. I was looking through the documentation and just trying to get something working. I really just want a legend for my second plot. The linear regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have multiple categories of data you shouldn't use `scatter/classes` with three separate classes. You'll get one "legend image" for each class, so the first two legend entries correspond to those two. As you can see the first symbol in the legend is a blue square, the second is a red triangle, corresponding to the scatter classes `a` and `b`.

The simplest modification to do would be to remove the two classes you don't use, i.e.

```
scatter/classes={
   b={mark=triangle*,red}
}
```

However, you might as well just drop all the scatter stuff, and just use `only marks, mark=triangle*, red`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics,fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(0,1)},anchor=north west},
ymin = 0.00071, 
ymax = 0.00214, 
clip = true,
clip mode=individual,
grid = major,
title=Voltage \& Current,
ylabel=Current,
xlabel=Voltage,
scaled ticks=false,
enlargelimits=0.2,
]
\addplot[opacity=.7,
   only marks,
   mark=triangle*,
   red
]
table {
x y
4.025 0.00071
6.042 0.00107
7.94 0.00140 
9.98 0.00177 
12 0.00214 
};
\addplot [opacity=.5] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{
X Y
4.025 0.000706862
6.042 0.001067945
7.94 0.001407724
9.98 0.001772924
12 0.002134544
};

\legend{Voltage,Current}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```